# NodeJS require from unknown child folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
-- plugins
---- myplugin1
------ core
---- myplugin2
------ core
```

If this is my directory structure, is there any way for me to import all `core` folders from `plugins` without knowing the name `myplugin1` etc?

```
require('/plugins/./core')
```

I know how to require from parent folders... but there seem to be nothing about child folders?

Comment: Read the directory `plugins`, for each file, check if it is a directory, read it and check if it has `core` directory.  If `true` require. It is an easy to do script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Node-Cheat](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/stackoverflow_answers/require_nested/app.js)** available [here](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/stackoverflow_answers/require_nested/app.js), run `node app` followed by `npm i glob`.

Possible try:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');

glob.sync('./plugins/**/core/*.js').forEach(( file ) => {
   require(path.resolve( file ) );
});
```

Expected output:

```
myplugin1 core loading
myplugin2 core loading
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [require-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir) to achieve this.

These will be the steps

`npm install require-file-directory`

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
var dir = requireDir('pathToyourCoreDirectory');
```

And inside the above handler function you can require all of the modules

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem. It still looks like I have to specify the name of the plugin folders. Care to explain into detail? The npmjs site doesn't really help me